# How to extract strings from one file into multiple files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I have a file, `xxx.lst` with the following data:

```
aaa 111  
bbb 222  
ccc 333
```

I need to make 3 files called `111.lst`, `222.lst` and `333.lst` respectively
with
`aaa` in `111.lst`
`bbb` in `222.lst`
and
`ccc` in `333.lst`

I tried something like this:

```
for x in $(cat xxx.lst|awk '{print $1}');do
    for y in $(cat xxx.lst|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d_ -f3|sort|uniq);do
        echo $x > $y.lst
    done
done
```

but it gives me `ccc` in all 3 files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible with a single awk command

```
awk '{print $1 > $2".lst"}' xxx.lst
```

Comment: Yea, awesome answer, thanks. Somewhere in back of my mind i knew it is extremely simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read var1 var2; do
    echo "$var1" > "$var2".lst
done < xxx.lst
```